# Format text file in particular way

Tags: python, bash, notepad++

I have a huge text file with a content like this:

```
1|ROW1|IDA|IDB|Z|OP
2|ROW2|IDA|IDC|IDF|IDG|Z|OP
3|ROW3|IDA|IDC|IDF|Z|OP
```

I would like to format it by flattening the `ID` columns like this:

```
1|ROW1|IDA|Z|OP
1|ROW1|IDB|Z|OP
2|ROW2|IDA|Z|OP
2|ROW2|IDC|Z|OP
2|ROW2|IDF|Z|OP
2|ROW2|IDG|Z|OP
3|ROW3|IDA|Z|OP
3|ROW3|IDC|Z|OP
3|ROW3|IDF|Z|OP
```

Is there any easy way of doing this in scripting? or do I need to write a small procedure to read each line and match each column of a line by regex?

thank you for your tips

Comment: @TedLyngmo - yes that is typo. thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Notepad++ solution using regular expressions. Tested on Notepad++ 7.9.1.

Find: `^(.*?\|)(ID\w\|)((?:ID\w\|)+)(.*)$`.
Replace with: `\1\2\4\r\n\1\3\4`.
Select regular-expressions and wrap-around, do not select dot-matches-newline.

Repeatedly do a replace-all until no more replaces are done. The number of replace-all commands needed will be one less than the maximum number of IDx strings in the lines.

Explanation of the find string:

```
^(.*?\|)        Group 1: Matches leading characters on the line
(ID\w\|)        Group 2: Matches the first IDx and its following |
(               Group 3 starts 
  (?:ID\w\|)+            Matches all remaining IDx's and their following |, this is a non-capturing group
)               Group 3 ends
(.*)$           Group 4: Everything on line after the last IDx and |
```

The Replace string outputs two lines. The first having the start (group 1) and end (group 4) texts enclosing the first IDx (group 2). The second line has the start and end texts surrounding the other IDx strings (group 3).

Comment: tested on Notepad++ 7.9.1, and the result is:
`
1|ROW1|IDA|Z|OP
2|ROW2|IDA|IDC|IDF|IDG|Z|OP
3|ROW3|IDA|IDC|IDF|Z|OP
1|ROW1|IDB|Z|OP
2|ROW2|IDA|IDC|IDF|IDG|Z|OP
3|ROW3|IDA|IDC|IDF|Z|OP`

Comment: @LeTex Then I think you need to read my answer again. Particulatly the bit about repeatedly doing a replace-all.

Comment: I am dealing with huge file, when do I stop the replace-all? it is going to be difficult to keep track

Comment: @LeTex that is also stated in the answer. Keep going until it finds no matches. It will need one less replace-all than the maximum number of IDx's in the lines.

Comment: It did work for the small example above (I just missed unticking dot-matches-newline check box). It actually also adapted very well if I add extra columns at the end or random lines. As expected, It is a bit slow for huge file, but it worked very well! accepting this one as an answer instead then ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to consider [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), you could do it like this:

```
awk -F'|' '{
    last = 2
    for(i = 3; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if($i~/^ID/) last = i;
        else break;
    }
    for(i = 3; i <= last; ++i) {
        printf("%s|%s|%s", $1, $2, $i);
        for(j = last + 1; j <= NF; ++j) {
            printf("|%s", $j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}'
```

For each line where the fields are separated by `|` (the `-F'|'` argument), this is what's done:

- The first loop finds the last field that starts with `ID` (the `/^ID/` part).
- The next loop loops over the `ID` fields and prints field 1 and 2 followed by the current `ID` field.
- The inner loop prints all the fields following the `ID` fields.

---

A version that is possibly easier to read and maintain:

```
awk -F'|' '{
    last = 2;
    for(i = 3; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if($i~/^ID/) last = i;
        else break;
    }

    last_fields = ""
    for(i = last + 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        last_fields = last_fields "|" $i;
    }

    for(i = 3; i <= last; ++i) {
        printf("%s|%s|%s%s\n", $1, $2, $i, last_fields);
    }
}'
```

- The first loop finds the last field that starts with `ID`.
- The second loop builds a variable (`last_fields`) out of the fields after the last `ID` field
- The third loop prints field 1, 2, the current `ID` field and then `last_fields`.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, up voted it according. Unfortunately I can not test `awk` at the moment.

Comment: @LeTex You're welcome!  Oh well, then the `awk` version is waiting here in case you need it in the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Python script here with the `csv` module:

```
with open('input.txt') as fdin, open('output.txt', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.reader(fdin, delimiter='|')
    wr = csv.writer(fdout, delimiter='|')
    for row in rd:
        for item in row[2:-2]:
            _ = wr.writerow(row[:2] + [item] + row[-2:])
```

Comment: that worked for the specific example I have provided. If I add any extra at the end of any of the line, it is not adapting well. For example if the first line is something like .. 1|ROW1|IDA|IDB|Z|OP|X|X

Comment: It is not working for extended cases, but this answer works for the provided example and the script can be adapted for other uses cases. Accepting it as answer therefore.

Comment: The notepad++ answer by @AdrianHHH works well for all use cases. Accepting that as an answer now.